# Table does not align in div in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, html-table

Internet Explorer is giving me a hard time here. I've made a WordPress theme and have made it mostly compatible with IE, all except for a table at the bottom of posts. This table is spilling over the side of the container div it's in, and it also seems too large in IE. (It should be 430 x 200 px) You can see the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vlyandra/kEm3R/

The Wordpress theme code used to generate each post looks like the following:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="bordered centered">
    <p class="negative-margin alignleft header"><?php the_title(); ?></p><p class="negative-margin alignright date"><?php the_date(); ?></p><div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="entry-content negative-margin">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):?>
            <div id="entry-left">
                <?php   $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');
                echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
                echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large'); 
                echo '</a>';?>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-right">
                <?php the_content( __( 'More <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'huckleberry' ) ); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'huckleberry' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
            </div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="entry-right">
                <table class="fixed-height fixed-width">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="valigned"><h3 class="date">Details</h3>
                            <?php the_field('details');?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="valigned">
                            <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');?>">
                                <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="valigned">
                            <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'tertiary-image');?>">
                                <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'tertiary-image'); endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="valigned">
                            <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'fourth-image');?>">
                                <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'fourth-image'); endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php the_content( __( 'More <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'huckleberry' ) ); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'huckleberry' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I'm terrible with IE, and would love any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following...

```
margin:0px auto; or
left:0; right:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the div it is in to the corect dimensions and do not want it spilling from that div...

Well then set the

CSS:

```
tblid{
width : 100%;
length : 100%;
}
```

Not sure if above is correct css format